# Android: Canvas made out of multiple images won't save

Tags: android, arrays, canvas, bitmap

Right my title isn't the best in the world. I've got a big code that's supposed to make on big bitmap out of multiple bitmaps. I've isolated the problem to this part of the code

```
bity = Bitmap.createBitmap(specialWidth,specialHeight,Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bity);

float left=0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i < imagesArrayz.length; i++){

     float top=0.0f;        
     canvas.drawBitmap(imagesArrayz[i], left, top, null);
     left+=imagesArrayz[i].getWidth();
}
```

To explain: "bity" is a globally defined Bitmap object and it's unassigned untill this point;
 imagesArrayz is an array of 5 Bitmaps that has already ben assigned and has ben assigned correctly (i tested it to see if each image is in the array)
After this i just have a function that saves the global variable bity to a file. THE PROBLEM is that instaid of saving my nicely drawn canvas it saves an empty jpg file of 0kb. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question... Replace ALPHA_8 with ARGB_8888 and it all magically works.

Someone shoot me please...